# How can I retrieve a value that is being parsed via JSON before triggering Airflow dag?

Tags: airflow

I'm having an airflow dag, where I'm parsing a JSON as the input before triggering it. I'm able to retrieve the value via **kwargs and push them into xcom as well within a PythonOperator method.

```
def push_to_xcom(ds, **kwargs):
    shape_change_tables = []
    ss_cd = {}
    env = ''

    if 'env' in kwargs['dag_run'].conf:
        env = kwargs['dag_run'].conf['env']
    else:
        env = 'dev'
        print("by default environment take as 'dev'")

    if isinstance(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['ss_cd'], dict):
        ss_cd = dict(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['ss_cd'])
    else:
        print('<<<<<<<<<<Pass sscd as an argument>>>>>>>>>>>')
        sys.exit(-1)
```

But what I'm not able to do is to retrieve the value outside the PythonOperator, which is within the dag script but not within any operators.

I've tried many options like using the Variable.set and Variable.get and also by using the Jinja template nothing worked. Can someone please let me know how could I retrieve a value in the dag script?

```
# setting it within a method after getting the value via kwargs
Variable.set(key="ss_cd", value=ss_cd)

ss_cd = airflow.models.Variable.get('ss_cd')
```

This is the sample JSON I'm passing:

```
{
"env":"qa",
"ss_cd":{"type":"sfdc","ss_cd":"sfdc"
}
```

Please let me know If I need to provide more details

Comment: Can you please explain the workflow as what you wish to achieve (rather what solution you choose) ? I can't seem to understand why would you want to push the conf to xcom

Comment: @Elad thanks for the response. Pushing to xcom was just a research per se. What I wanted to achieve is to be able to retrieve the parsed values outside any operators in the dag script

Comment: For what reason? If you are looking for a way to build you DAG structure with the context - this is an anti pattern.

Comment: @Elad It's not to build the dag structure but to use the value that I parsed in to execute a python method in parallel.

Comment: but executing python method is done via PythonOperator and it the context so why "to be able to retrieve the parsed values outside any operators"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract the values by using the following:

```
conf = dag.get_dagrun(execution_date=dag.latest_execution_date).conf
env= conf['env']
ss_cd = dict(conf['ss_cd'])
```